# Firebird 2.5 update or insert into

Tags: sql, firebird, insert-update, firebird2.5

I can't figure out how to write a SQL statement in Firebird so it should add new row, and if some conditions meet to update also other column.

Example:

(in MySql looks like this:)

```
insert into 
table (col1, col2, col3) values ('a', 'b', 'c')
on duplicate key update col4=col3;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options in Firebird

### UPDATE OR INSERT

You can use [`UPDATE OR INSERT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-update-or-insert):

```
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3)
  VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c')
  MATCHING (col1, col2)
```

The `MATCHING`-clause is optional. If you leave it out, it will use the primary key:

> UPDATE OR INSERT inserts a new record or updates one or more existing
> records. The action taken depends on the values provided for the
> columns in the MATCHING clause (or, if the latter is absent, in the
> primary key). If there are records found matching those values, they
> are updated. If not, a new record is inserted.

Contrary to the code in your question, this will not allow you to customize the update: it will use the same values as would be inserted.

If you want more control, use merge

### MERGE

The [`MERGE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-merge) statement gives you more control, but can be a bit more verbose:

```
MERGE INTO table AS t
  USING (select 'a' as new1, 'b' as new2, 'c' as new3 from rdb$database) as s
    ON t.col1 = s.new1 and t.col2 = s.new2
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET t.col4 = t.col3
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (col1, col2, col3) values (s.new1, s.new2, s.new3)
```

However contrary to `UPDATE OR INSERT`, `MERGE` can't use the primary key implicitly. You will need to specify the duplicate rules yourself in the `ON` clause.